# How to check one specific field is null or not using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have a database table `Wys_teachers` with the following table fields

- id
- t_adate
- t_amonth
- t_ayear
- t_attendance

I am inserting the following values:

1, 15, 07, 2015, 1
2, 15, 07, 2015, 1
3, 15, 07, 2015, 1
4, 15, 07, 2015, 0, go to hospital
5, 15, 07, 2015, 1

Then I want to update `id=4` so that `t_attendance` becomes 1 at a time plus the `t_areason` field is empty (remove `go to hospital`).

My contrller  update code is:

```
`if(!$teachers->isEmpty()) {
    foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
        $updatet_attendance = WysTeacherattendance::where('t_auserid',$teacher->user_id)
            ->where('t_adate', $date_exploded[0])
            ->where('t_amonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('t_ayear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->update(array(
                't_attendance'=>Input::get($teacher->user_id),
        )); 

        $allattendance= WysTeacherattendance::where('t_auserid',$teacher->user_id)
            ->where('t_adate', $date_exploded[0])
            ->where('t_amonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('t_ayear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->get();
            $reason=$allattendance->t_areason;

            if(!$allattendance->isEmpty()) {
                DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
                ->where('t_auserid',$teacher->user_id)
                ->where('t_adate','=',$date_exploded[0])
                ->where('t_amonth','=',$date_exploded[1])
                ->where('t_ayear','=',$date_exploded[2])
                ->where('t_aresaon','!=',NULL)
                ->delete();
            }
        }
        //return Redirect::route('GetTeachersearchAttendence')
            // ->with('success','update teacher exist');     
    }
}`
```

Update condition is fine - the `t_attendance = 0`-value becomes `t_attendance = 1`. But `t_areason` is not deleted.

This Part of code is not working:

```
`$allattendance= WysTeacherattendance::where('t_auserid',$teacher->user_id)
    ->where('t_adate', $date_exploded[0])
    ->where('t_amonth', $date_exploded[1])
    ->where('t_ayear', $date_exploded[2])
    ->get();
 $reason=$allattendance->t_areason;

if(!$allattendance->isEmpty()) {
    DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
        ->where('t_auserid',$teacher->user_id)
        ->where('t_adate','=',$date_exploded[0])
        ->where('t_amonth','=',$date_exploded[1])
        ->where('t_ayear','=',$date_exploded[2])
        ->where('t_aresaon','!=',NULL)
        ->delete();
 }`
```

I dont know if this is correct or wrong.

How to solve this problem?
And how to check if one specific field is null or not?

Comment: Don't want to sound rude, but how can you debug code that is formatted like the one you've posted here? Took me a while to reformat this mess...